# why i am unable to add some files to my git repository?

Tags: postgresql, git, docker

i'm trying to learn how to create a git repository.

i have a working directory where my app resides on the server.

/**home/app/abd**

steps i've taken so far:

```
~/abd$ git init <--create repo
~/abd$ git add ./ <--stage all the files in my directory
```

**but now i've run into this:**

```
       new file:   media/root/pics/Volvo_XC90_T8eAWDPlug-InHybridInscription7Passenger.png
        new file:   media/root/pics/Volvo_XC90_T8eAWDPlug-InHybridInscriptionExpression6Passenger.png
        new file:   media/root/pics/Volvo_XC90_T8eAWDPlug-InHybridInscriptionExpression7Passenger.png
        new file:   media/root/pics/Volvo_XC90_T8eAWDPlug-InHybridR-Design7Passenger.png
        new file:   pga.tar.gz

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   _volumes/pg_db1/pgdata/pg_stat_tmp/db_0.stat
        modified:   _volumes/pg_db1/pgdata/pg_stat_tmp/db_16384.stat
        modified:   _volumes/pg_db1/pgdata/pg_stat_tmp/db_24724.stat
        modified:   _volumes/pg_db1/pgdata/pg_stat_tmp/global.stat
```

**so my question is:**

is this because i'm running postgres in a container and my website is live?

i don't really want to stop the postgres instance, i just want to capture all of the current data...and it happens to be that my volumes are inside the working directory...

Comment: I don't understand. Don't add all the files if you don't want to add them all..

Comment: @GaëlJ i do want to add all the files...my question is why were some of them not staged...

Comment: These data doesn't look like something you should ever commit to a Git repo..

Comment: Notice that git isn't meant to be used with binary files. "Backing up" the database in such a way is not a use case for git.

Comment: @GaëlJ can i ask why? im trying to understand what the best practices are..i thought i was supposed to put everything in one folder

Comment: @Turing85 ahhh ok thanks! so, basically i should separate volumes from the repo?

Comment: It's a really, really bad idea to put Postgres' data directory into git. This is not going to work properly. Which problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: I do not understand why you want to "back up" the database in such a way. If you want to back up the database, use `pg_dump` to create a database dump.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i see i see! i'm just trying to figure out best way way to backup my project that i have in a server.. i thought thats what a repo was for

Comment: @Turing85 i was trying to back up my project...the project folder happens to include the volumes for a postgres container

Comment: i guess this is a case where i should include a .gitignore and include the postgres volume in there

Comment: so..i get the general idea here: don't do this.  but just out of curiosity...why wasnt i ABLE to? is it just baked into git not to include binaries? i wouldn't think so since some projects need them no? again im cluelss

Comment: You should ignore these files by including them in .gitignore.  But why you're not able to check them in depends on various factors one of which is the created user.  Could you check who owns these files?If you're using default docker container user which is root, these files should be owned by root on the host system as well.  If you're not logged in as the root user on the host machine you'll not be able to check these in.

Comment: @vivekveeramani ahh super interesting..so my user is sudo and the subfolders all seem to belong to my user so thats curious.  and actually the containers are running under my user.  but that's definitely likely.

Comment: You should put your SQL scripts that create your tables into git, not the Postgres installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a general problem here, and it applies to Git as well as to Postgres (or Ingres or MongoDB or, well, pretty much any database you can name, though eventually-consistent distributed databases like [Cassandra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) in its usual configuration, have *built in* ways to deal with this).  The general problem is called the [*CAP theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

Backing up a database consists of *making a copy*, by definition.  This in turn represents a *distribution* of the data in the database: you now have a *distributed database*.

The CAP theorem tells us that any distributed database must give up at least one of three guarantees: *consistency* (data retrieved from the database matches, e.g., your bank balance at ATM #1 isn't mysteriously different from your bank balance at ATM #2), *availability* (your bank balance is available at all ATMs), and *partition tolerance* (even if the bank's network goes down, you can still use the ATMs).

Git itself can be viewed as software that manipulates a pair of databases in tandem: there's an *object database* holding the commits and other supporting objects, and a *names database* holding branch and other names, needed to *find* the objects.  (Git manages its own distributed-ness by giving up consistency across databases: you must use `git fetch` and/or `git push` to synchronize them, which you can only do when the two are not partitioned, i.e., the network is up between them.)

Again, any time you make a backup, or for that matter, put something on a network drive, you're creating duplicates: a sort of distributed database.  This forces you into a CAP-theorem choice: what will you give up?  But any one given database has already made its own choice.  Some SQL setups give up nothing, at the cost of not allowing partitions at all: you literally *can't* copy the database, at least not if it's live.  Any copy—any backup—is *automatically invalid*.

They may give you a "dump" option that produces a consistent snapshot that can be used to restore the data as-of-then.  You'll lose subsequent transactions, but you've *already agreed that this is the right answer*, so *you must use this protocol*.  You don't just back up the database somehow: you invoke the dump operation, and put the dumped data into the backup.

So, any time you have some database software and are looking for ways to make backups for disaster recovery and the like, always check the instructions.  How does *this* database say to do that?  Follow those instructions.  Don't just use Git, or your OS's "snapshot the tree" operation, or whatever: those may not be reliable.

Comment: thanks for this, not sure why there are so many asshats on stackoverflow, but people like you make it awesome